# Creating Message --> Bot Reaction

Tags: discord, discord.js

Id like write a Program, that will send a message/bot-command ("!work") into a discord channel every 2min with my User-ID.
It worked, but the bot doesnt respond/react to that message.

Code:

```
bot.on("message", msg => {

    function work() {
        let guild = bot.guilds.get('695350286516092968'), channel;
        channel = guild.channels.get('719889410149318696').send("!work");
        console.log(new Date() + " " + msg);

    }

    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "_money")) {
        console.log(new Date() + " " + msg);
        setInterval(work, 120000);
    };
}
);

const prefix = "$Bot";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function work() {
    let guild = bot.guilds.get('695350286516092968'), channel;
    channel = guild.channels.get('719889410149318696').send("!work");
    message.react("")
    console.log(new Date() + " " + msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you would need to handle that message by adding an if statement

```js
if(msg.content === "!work") {
  //logic
  msg.channel.send("Hey");
}
```

There are a few future errors with the current code you have though, one: you could be setting multiple intervals, a way to fix this is just to have an interval variable which you set it to, this way you could also clear the interval later on if you wanted to

```js
const prefix = "$Bot";
let interval;

function work() {
        const channel = bot.channels.get('719889410149318696');
        channel.send("!work");
        console.log(new Date() + " " + msg);
}

bot.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "_money")) {
        if(interval) return;
        console.log(new Date() + " " + msg);
        interval = setInterval(work, 120000);
    };
});
```

Comment: The Second Bot, that doesnt react to my SelfBot message, isnt my own bot, so i cant change the code. And after i changed my code like u said, it still doesnt work. Does Bots respond to Selfbot messages?

Comment: Most bots are coded not to respond to bots. You can code it to, but they chose not to. No way to fix.